# Unable to find certificate chain on calling external service in java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl-certificate, weblogic12c

I have the following exception on trying to call an external service in my spring boot application, from a @Configuration class

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: Unable to find certificate chain.
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:237)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:232)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: Unable to find certificate chain.
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathBuilderSpi.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I have already set trustStore in my environment variable

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Projects\keystoreORG\CertsKeystore
```

The thing that I don't understand is that I created a simple static main application which do the same call to the same webservice and it works.I don't know why it is not working with my spring boot application

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Your truststore must either contain the server's certificate (not recommended) or the certificate's issuer(s), which are usually some intermediate or a root CA (certificate authority). Obviously, your truststore does not, hence the exception.

Comment: can you try System.setProperty() for setting your trustStore and trustStorePassword

Comment: I tried System.setProperty() but not worked. The thing that I don't understand is that I created a simple static main application which do the same call to the same webservice and it works. I don't know why it is not working with my spring boot application

Comment: The JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS env var is not used by WebLogic Server scripts. Use JAVA_OPTIONS instead.